# Update scaling without restart / relogin in KDE?

Tags: 18.04, dell, display-resolution, kde5, scaling

I am using Kubuntu 18.04.3 with KDE 5.12.9 on my Dell Precision 5530 which has a 4k screen. As I quite frequently connect a display (mostly just 1080p) and KDE does not yet support scaling per screen I need to change the scaling factor. 
Usually I set the laptop screen to 1080p with 1x scaling, but I always need to restart or relogin to apply the changes, which is quite tedious since all open thing get closes. As solution I tried to restart the plasmashell, but that does not work very well since the title bars does not get scaled properly after that.
Is there an option that the system does it automatically, as it Gnome? 
Might it help to change SDDM to LightDM? Not sure if this actually makes more changes than just the loginscreen.

Thanks for help

Comment: This [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/7j2jzn/kde_multidpi_xrandrkrandr_experiences/) on r/kde (Reddit) may help you. Someone proposed to use Wayland rather than X11. Caveat: I do not have experiences with wayland. Before you want to try consult with this [article](https://www.secjuice.com/wayland-vs-xorg/).

Comment: Thank I will check it out. I used wayland for some time, but it seems not that stable yet and things like global menu do not work properly. Furthermore I have huge problems using Libreoffice, since the whole window decorations are gone.

Comment: @ZoltanFabian I tried using it, but it simply is not as reliable as it should be and a lot of thing do not work properly, e.g. LibreOffice has not window decorations.
Let's hope there will be a better solution in near future.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell </dev/null &>/dev/null &` in a shell, but you'll still have to restart applications for the scaling to be applied